# Firebase Push Notifications Active Campaigns

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Where I can view all my account's active campaigns? I've checked the 'Engage' settings but couldn't find any options. I know we have active push notifications set up for our app from an operational perspective. What steps can I take to access this information?